# How to know if an element is going outside of a grid-container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a simple project with a character and grid template. The idea is, when the character is moving, to move the grid template.

HTML File:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script defer src="main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
    <img id="inFront" src="inFront.png" width="200px">

    <div id="insideBox" class="insideBox"> 
        <div id="pageOne" class="pageOne"></div>
        <div id="pageTwo" class="pageTwo"></div>
        <div id="pageThree" class="pageThree"></div>
        <div id="pageFour" class="pageFour"></div>
        <div id="pageFive" class="pageFive"></div>
        <div id="pageSix" class="pageSix"></div>
        <div id="pageSeven" class="pageSeven"></div>
        <div id="pageEight" class="pageEight"></div>
        <div id="pageNine" class="pageNine"></div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and css:

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.box {
    width: 99vw;
    height: 99vh;   
    background-color: gray;
    z-index: -1;
}

.insideBox {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    width: 300vw;
    height: 300vh;

    position: relative;

}
```

So, in this case, we have the div `box` and inside `box` we have another div, called `insideBox`. `insideBox` is a grid container with 9 child elements. I have a JS file which detects user input (W A S D) and allows me to move my character around the page.

Once the character hits the bottom of the viewpoint, the container (`insideBox`) changes it's position. Please look at this: [image]

And here is my problem: I can go outside that div `insideBox` (the gray color on the .gif means that I am outside the grid). How can I make it so, if I go outside the grid nothing would change? So, it is not possible for my character to go outside `insideBox`

Comment: my eyes hurts ....

Comment: You would probably want to use the offsetLeft and offsetTop to measure the position of the character and compare it to the offsetLeft and offsetTop of the container to see which one it's inside.

Comment: @raphael75 I don’t know why I didn’t think of this, it worked, thank you

Comment: I will add it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it is best to check the offsetLeft and offsetTop of the character and compare it to the offsetLeft and offsetTop of the container (taking into account the width/height as well) to determine which container the character is inside. Reference: http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/elementproperties.shtml